# Updating field containing single ` (backtick) with a NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to import data from a source that I have no control of the data quality.  I know how to remove/replace most anything but I have encountered a field that contains a single ` (backtick), I need to replace this with a NULL.  I am needing to remove the backtick because I convert the data from the varchar field that it is to a numeric.  I have tried versions of this:

```
Update dbo.Sale
Set Stamps = NULL
where Stamps = ''''
```

Comment: Your code should work, might be, that there are spaces around? Try `WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Stamps))=''''`

Comment: If this does not help, try to find out, if the sign you see is a normal single quote acutally: `SELECT CAST(Stamps AS VARBINARY(1)) FROM dbo.Sales` This should show up as `0x27` (and nothing else), if this is really nothing else than a simple quote.

Comment: Well I'm sure all of these solutions would work, I messed it it wasn't a ' it was a ` (backtick).  Excuse me while I get some caffeine, put on my glasses, and pull head from rear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CHAR(39)` for clarity's sake:

```
UPDATE dbo.Sale
SET Stamps = NULL
WHERE Stamps = CHAR(39);
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (MyColumn VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @t
        ( MyColumn )
VALUES  ( ''''  -- MyColumn - varchar(255)
          )

SELECT * 
FROM @t

UPDATE @t
SET MyColumn = NULL
WHERE MyColumn = CHAR(39)

SELECT *
FROM @t
```

OR

```
UPDATE @t
    SET MyColumn = NULL
    WHERE MyColumn = ''''
```